# What is the difference between std::sort and std::stable_sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like to know how std::sort and std::stable_sort differ with respect to functionality, memory and hardware? The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) mentions that "Sorts the elements in the range [first,last) into ascending order, like sort, but stable_sort preserves the relative order of the elements with equivalent values.", but that didn't make sense to me. What is the "relative order" and "equivalent values"?

Comment: `std::sort` usually uses introsort, and `std::stable_sort` merge sort

Comment: A question isn't off-topic because the answer can be found elsewhere on the internet...the whole point of SO is to provide a quick-to-consult reference for users for programming problems. So while you can down-vote as 'unclear or not useful', it doesn't really seem to be 'off-topic'. IMHO.

Comment: @nbrooks Then the OP should clearly ask for the reference or what is unclear about it, or you should edit the question to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Asking for the documentation or asking what is unclear about the documentation *would* be off topic though. SO is not here to tell people where to find documentation, nor to clarify said documentation for people. It is here to provide answers, almost all of which can be found in *some* documentation, somewhere.

Comment: This is a very valid question. Even I didn't understand the documentation and reached here to find the answers. Similar questions have been asked on SO many times when people wanted to know the difference between STL datastructures etc. OP secured a gold medal for this question, which shows how valuable it has been for so many more programmers who didn't understand the documentation.

Comment: A sorting algorithm is *stable* if elements that compare as equal keep their original relative positions.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, it's as you said, and this is not a concept unique to C++.

**Stable sorts preserve the physical order of semantically equivalent values.**

---

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

> The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.
>   **Complexity:** `O(N·log(N))`, where `N` = `std::distance(first, last)` comparisons

[`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort):

> The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved.
>   **Complexity:** `O(N·log^2(N))`, where `N` = `std::distance(first, last)` applications of `cmp`. If additional memory is available, then the complexity is `O(N·log(N))`.

The implication is that `std::stable_sort` cannot be performed quite as efficiently in terms of execution time, unless "additional memory is available" in which case it is not being performed as efficiently in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Empirically, for an array of size 65536, I find that stable_sort is *faster* than sort. I conclude that "cannot be performed quite as efficiently" is not the full story.

Comment: @JoachimW As is the case with any algorithm, we are talking only about growth rates, and it is perfectly to be expected that one algorithm may be faster than the other with small inputs, but that the performance of the former degrades quicker than the latter as the number of inputs grows. As such, I'd be interested to find out what results you get when you exchange 65536 for [many] other numbers. (I will concede that my wording glossed over this possibility.)

Comment: Outcome may also depend in subtle ways on any partial order present in the input data, right?

Comment: @JoachimW stable_sort will likely be faster for some input sets, particularly ones with lots of equivalent elements, simply because it goes straight for the "definitely O(n log n)" approach rather than struggling through a few levels of introsort first. I would not expect it to be faster than stable_sort for a shuffled array of 2^16 unique integers, though.

Answer (score 19):

I think that an example with sorting a struct, rather than a list of integers, is helpful to clarify what the difference is between both.

Imagine a list of neighbours in a building, that you construct ordered by the floor where they live.

```
struct Neighbour
{
   int floor;
   string name;
   Neighbour(int f, string n) : floor(f), name(n) {}
};

std::vector<Neighbour> vec = {Neighbour(1,Bob), Neighbour(2,Anna), ... };
```

- 1 Bob
- 2 Anna
- 3 Peter
- 4 Bob
- 5 Laura

If you now want to sort your list alphabetically, and you use

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](Neighbour a, Neighbour b){ return a.name < b.name; }
```

the result might be:

- 2 Anna
- 1 Bob
- 4 Bob
- 5 Laura
- 3 Peter

or:

- 2 Anna
- 4 Bob
- 1 Bob
- 5 Laura
- 3 Peter

With `stable_sort`, it is ensured that you always will get the first result. With the duplicates in the same order they were in the initial list.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned, the standard only notes that std::stable_sort preserves the original order for equal elements, while std::sort doesn't.

In the case of HP / Microsoft STL, std::sort is usually quick sort, unless the nesting gets too deep, in which case it switched to heap sort. Quick sort time complexity is typically O(n log(n)), but it's worst case is O(n^2), which is avoided with the switch to heap sort, since heap sort is always O(n log(n)) (but slower than quick sort so it's only used to avoid O(n^2)).

In the case of HP / Microsoft STL, std::stable_sort is a hybrid bottom up merge sort, using insertion sort to create sorted groups of 32 elements, then doing bottom up merge sort with the groups. The array (or vector) is split into two, a temporary array (or vector) 1/2 the size of the array to be sorted is allocated, and used to do a merge sort for both halfs of the array. Then one of the half arrays is moved to the temp array to do a final merge pass. Merge sort is also O(n log n), taking a bit longer for sorting arrays of objects, but merge sort is often faster if sorting an array of pointers to objects where a comparison function is included in the call. This because merge sort involves more moves but fewer compares than quick sort.

For sorting an array of integers, a radix sort is faster. If sorting by byte, then it takes 4 passes to sort an array of 32 bit integers, and 8 passes to sort an array of 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 6):

As you correctly realized, `std::stable_sort()` retains the relative order of objects considered equivalent. `std::sort()` doesn't have this requirement. As a result, `std::stable_sort()` is likely to be more resource-hungry: it will probably be slower and will probably use more temporary memory as it has to obey more constraints. I'm not aware of any algorithm which does in-place stable sorting as efficient as sorting.

Comment: I think an example would've helped best. I understood it as if I have `[s1, s2, s3]` as `[3, 2, 2]` and do a `stable_sort` on the array to obtain [2, 2, 3], then `stable_sort` ensures that the array order remains as `[s2, s3, s1]` instead of there being a chance of `s2` and `s3`'s positions getting mixed up. Correct?

Comment: Nav : Yes correct