# How is the order of occurence maintained by the given conditions

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I came accross this GeeksForGeeks which read : Rearrange positive and negative numbers using inbuilt sort function such that all negative integers appear before all the positive integers and **the order of appearance should be maintained**.

The comparator function of sort() was modified to achieve this.

```
bool comp(int a, int b)
{
    // This is to maintain order
    if ((a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
        return false;

    // Swapping is must
    if ((a >= 0) && (b < 0))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

But how come the order is maintained by this block :

```
if ((a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
    return false;
```

Comment: if `a < 0` and `b > 0` the `comp` function returns nothing right now, that's undefined behavior already.

Comment: I can't help but think that the function shown also breaks [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is another case of UB.

Comment: I would have tried [`stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) if the ordering has to be preserved.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be the original article

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-positive-negative-numbers-using-inbuilt-sort-function/

How it (sort of) works:  std::sort rearranges everything according to a comparitor. This comparitor is based on "all negative numbers are exactly equal to each other. All positive numbers are exactly equal to each other. Negative numbers are smaller than positive numbers."

If you sort according to those rules, you are going to get all the negative numbers then all the positive numbers. The comparitor itself does not mess with their order, beyond looking at whether they are greater or less than zero. (And the data set conveniently doesn't have any zeroes.)

What's wrong:

1) The comparison function does not correctly handle 0. It gives wrong answers, and even worse, it gives answers which violate strict weak ordering. (see below)

2) std::sort is not a stable sort. It is not guaranteed to preserve order. They got lucky on one data set. If they had used std::stable_sort, and a correct comparison function, it would have been a "built in function" which met the requirements. But the comparison function alone can't make an algorithm stable. See [What is the difference between std::sort and std::stable_sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985891/what-is-the-difference-between-stdsort-and-stdstable-sort) or just look near the top of the docs on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

3) They do fancy tricks to come up with a solution of complexity O(n log n), for a trivially easy O(n) problem. So besides being wrong on multiple points, it is inefficient for no good reason.

Perhaps they should have considered https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition if we're allowed to just rule out zeroes in the data.

---

Here is a definition of strict weak ordering (also linked by Some Programmer Dude)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings

```
For all x in S, it is not the case that x < x (irreflexivity).
For all x, y in S, if x < y then it is not the case that y < x (asymmetry).
For all x, y, z in S, if x < y and y < z then x < z (transitivity).
For all x, y, z in S, if x is incomparable with y (neither x < y nor y < x hold), and y is incomparable with z, then x is incomparable with z (transitivity of incomparability).
```

Note that comp(0, anything) returns false, so 1 < 0 which makes it easy to break transitivity, in addition to being obviously wrong.

Comment: comp (0, 0) returns false in the original posters function, not true. Irreflexivity is maintained.

Comment: quite right, comp(0, anything) is a constant, but I had the wrong value in first scan. It looks like comp(x, y) is always false if x >= 0, so the error is even more general.

Answer (score 0):

> But how come the order is maintained by this block :

The order is not "maintained" in the comparator. The comparator can only tell that after sorting, two elements a and b should be end up

- a before b
- a after b
- a together with b (before the same elements, after the same elements)

What happens to elements that are not ordered by the comparator is only a function of the algorithm. For insertion in a multiset, the added element would end up anywhere (except when insert with hint is used).

Answer (score -1):

The comp function breaks strict weak ordering for

```
if ((a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
    return false;
```

If a is 0 and b is +ve, then a is less than b, but false is returned, not true

Try

```
bool comp(int a, int b)
{
   const int first = ((a < 0) ? -1 : (a == 0) ? 0 : 1);
   const int second = ((b < 0) ? -1 : (b == 0) ? 0 : 1);

   return (first < second);
}
```

and plug that into std::stable_sort

Comment: "_comp function breaks strict weak ordering_" for which numbers?

Comment: It depends on whether  0 is regarded as +ve number. If it is not, try a = 0 and b= 2. If you plug that into the original comp(), false is returned when 0 < 2 is true.